# Visual Studio 2015 - find all instances of space before closing double quotation

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I want to perform a search that will find spaces before closing double quotation marks (the actual match will be the space and the closing double quotation mark). I think I need a regex to do this but I don't have much experience with it.

These test cases should help:
"This sentence should produce a match. "
"This sentence should produce a match "
Quotes can be found anywhere like "here " in my code.

"This sentence should not produce a match."
"This sentence should not produce a match"
Quotes can be found anywhere like "here" in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out.

```
 "(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```